# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php

This is part of my code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","baspdata",3306);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{ 
echo "Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}
else
{ 
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM member WHERE Username='$username' and Password = '$password'");
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
$sellerId=$row['MemberId'];
$picturecontent= file_get_contents($productPic);    
$query ="INSERT INTO product (ProductName, ProductPicture, ProductDescription, ProductCategory, ProductPrice, UploadedDate, Sold, SellerId) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?.?)";
$stmt=$con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $productName, $picturecontent, $description, $category, $price, $uploadedDate, $sold , $sellerId);
$stmt->execute();
$con->close();
echo "<h1>".$productName." added successfully! =)<br/> </h1>"; 

}
```

I get the error Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object  on the line $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $productName, $picturecontent, $description, $category, $price, $uploadedDate, $sold , $sellerId); but i can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` means exactly what it says. The `$stmt` object is not an object -- this happens when the `prepare` call fails and returns `false` instead of returning an object.

Comment: If you read the php documentation page for `prepare` you'll see that it clearly states that `prepare` returns `false` on failure. Which means you always need to check if the returned value is `false` before using it as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query fail and dont return the prepared stament look,

```
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?.?)
```

change to

```
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```